# Order Django Query Results by Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model that is set up as follows:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
```

I know this does not work, but is there any other way I can run a query something like this:

```
Logs.objects.filter(date=someDate).order_by('name__last_name')
```

I just need the final result to be a `QuerySet` ordered by the last name of the User that is related by the `ForeignKey`.

I'm really at my wits end about this one.
Anything would help: some method that I haven't look at, an actual raw SQL query or even just a general idea to pursue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you added an s to Log in your query. That should be `Log.objects.filter(date=someDate).order_by('name__last_name')`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The query you entered looks valid.

Look at the order by docs [**`here`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

Is it not working for you?

**for example** (formatted for easier reading):

```
    >>> units = Unit.objects.filter(color='red').order_by('location__label')
    >>> print units.query
    SELECT `samples_unit`.`id`, `samples_unit`.`location_id`, `samples_unit`.`color` 
      FROM `samples_unit` 
INNER JOIN `storages_container` 
        ON (`samples_unit`.`location_id` = `storages_container`.`id`) 
     WHERE `samples_unit`.`color` = red  
  ORDER BY `storages_container`.`label` ASC
```

Comment: It does work, now that is. @DTing pointed a very trivial spelling error I had in my call that was causing the entire problem. Somehow I just was unable to deduce that from the error messages!