# Maintaining order of querylist

Tags: django, django-models

I have a query that looks like this:

```
top_posts= Ranking.objects.all().order_by("-score").values("post")
```

It gets the top posts ordered by score and then this query is executed:

```
Posts.objects.filter(id__in=top_posts)
```

However, the `order_by` score is thrown away when I run this query. How do I maintain the order of the score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have relationship, you can try some thing like this

```
Posts.objects.filter(id__in=top_posts).order_by('-id__score')
```

for your reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750409/order-django-query-results-by-foreign-key)

Hope this helps you...